# Acoustic signal processing using Python

Tags: python, signals, fft, frequency, dft

I am new to python & its libraries and need some guide. I have measured time domain signals (volts) and need to upload this data to python and do a a fast fourier transform

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Why don't you take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think it could be useful for you and the commmunity.

Comment: always assume the question you have has already been asked so you must search hard and long for tid bits of clues possibly scattered across the net ... here on SO always show your code you have battled with when posting a question ... please carefully read the link in above comment ... welcome to SO